# Password Hash::check not working (SQL+Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I use laravel framework for my website login system.
I then created an android application for the website and created a separate **login.php** in order to let people login from the android app. This file is uploaded at **public_html** directory.

The problem users can't login until **Hash::check** is verified. **Hash::check** is not working for some resasons I don't know!!

**login.php**

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Hash;

 

$email = 'xxxx';
$password = 'xxxx';
$token = $_POST["token"];

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($result) {

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1 ) {
        
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $hashPassword = '$row["password"]'; 
    
        if (Hash::check($password, $hashPassword))
        {  
            $response = array("success" => "1", "user_details" => $row, "message"=>"You have been logged in successfully");
        }


    } else {
        $response = array("success" => "0", "message"=>"Please enter valid email and password");
    }
     
 } else {
      $response = array("success" => "0", "message"=>"Server error");
 }
 
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**Update:**

I manually tried Hash::make and Hash::check but they are not working!

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

hash password manually:

```html
$password = 'JohnDoe';
    $hashedPassword = Hash::make($password);
    echo $hashedPassword;
```

Comment: you must learn laravel and elequent ,I guess you didn't even see a laravel course or read some parts of laravel docs  
at least please read these pages to understand what you must do 

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#hashing-passwords

Comment: Brother, I read a alot but I can't hashing is not working at all. See my update!

Comment: @JavaDava Could you please share your login.php code?

Comment: @Arash Sure, but take in mind that login.php is just a login code for android app users to connect to sql database of the website. It differe from website login system which is laravel.
brother, I can't update the thread, but my login.php code the same as your answer down with adding my updates.

Comment: @Arash code: https://pastebin.com/yv4Wpb56

Comment: @JavaDava You need to follow the laravel framework structure if you intend to use this framework.  Before starting your project, you should watch some tutorials about laravel.  https://youtu.be/376vZ1wNYPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This might be a temporarily solution that worked for me.
I fetched the hashed password from database and compared it with posted one.**

**I replaced:**

```html
Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword)
```

**With:**

```html
password_verify($password, $hashedPassword)
```

```html
<?php

 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 $token = $_POST["token"];

 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$email'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 if($result){
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>= 1 ) {
         $json_array['user_details'] = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $json_array['user_details'][] = $row;
                $roww = $row['password'];
            }

if(password_verify($password, $roww)){

         $response = array("success" => "1", "user_details" => $json_array, "message"=>"You have been logged in successfully");

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET token='$token' WHERE email='$email'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
             
         
        }else{
         $response = array("success" => "0", "message"=>"Please enter valid email and password");
         }
     
        }
        }else{
      $response = array("success" => "0", "message"=>"Server error");
       }
 
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($response);
```